# What is the best way to handle dependencies based on the Python version?

Tags: python, setuptools

If I have a setup.py using SetupTools, is there a way to specify install_requires for a specific version of Python?

E.g., if one of my modules requires the use of an OrderedDict, I would like versions of Python <2.7 to install the ordereddict1.1 package from PyPI, but there's no reason to (and probably a bad idea) to add that to a Python 2.7 installtion.

What's the best way to handle this? Separate eggs for the different versions? I know that's necessary for non-pure modules but this would be pure Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `setup.py` is just plain Python code, so you do the exact same thing you do in your source code in the setup script.

---

The documentation shows how to switch on `sys.version_info` for doing 3.x vs. 2.x code, but it works the same way for 2.7 vs. 2.6. So, if your code is doing this:

```
if sys.version_info < (2, 7);
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict
else:
    from collections import OrderedDict
```

… then your setup script can do this:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup

extra_install_requires = []
if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    extra_install_requires.append('ordereddict>=1.1')

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires = [...] + extra_install_requires,
    # ...
)
```

---

On the other hand, if your code is doing this:

```
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    from ordereddict import OrderedDict
```

… then, while you *could* use `version_info`, you might as well just do this:

```
extra_install_requires = []
try:
    from collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    extra_install_requires.append('ordereddict>=1.1')
```

---

Either way, if you, e.g., `pip-2.5 install` this package, it'll download and install the `ordereddict` module (unless the user already has 1.1 or later); with 2.7, it won't do anthying.

---

If you're looking to distribute pre-built eggs, then yes, they will end up different for Python 2.6 and 2.7. For example, after `python2.6 setup.py bdist_egg && python2.7 setup.py bdist_egg`, you will end up with `dist/Foo-0.1-py2.6.egg` and `dist/Foo-0.1-py2.7.egg`, and you will have to distribute both of them.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the quick and thorough response.

Comment: You've got a semicolon in `if sys.version_info < (2, 7);`

Answer (score 0):

You could just check for the python version and dynamically append the requirement for older python versions:

```
from setuptools import setup
import sys

install_requires = [
   # your global requirements
   # ...
]

if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    install_requires.append('ordereddict >= 1.1')

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=install_requires
    # ...
)
```